# What is the Rosseland mean opacity a function of?

Tags: astrophysics, stars

For a given star, (if anything) what is the Rosseland mean opacity a function of? For example, does it depend on distance from the center?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [definition of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opacity_(optics)#Planck_and_Rosseland_opacities):
$$
\kappa_r^{-1}=\frac{\int \kappa_\nu^{-1}u\left(\nu,\,T\right)\,{\rm d}\nu}{\int u\left(\nu,\,T\right)\,{\rm d}\nu}
$$
with $u\left(\nu,\,T\right)={\rm d}B_\nu\left(T\right)/{\rm d}T$ is the temperature-derivative of the Planck function and $\kappa_\nu$ the frequency-dependent opacity. Clearly this depends on temperature. Less clearly, it depends on the material the light is passing through, so there's a chemical composition dependence here (typically denoted as $X_i$). Since it represents light as passing through a medium, the density of the medium plays a role.

Thus, it seems the general function is $\kappa_r\left(\rho,\,T,\,X_i\right)$.